# How to create iTerm2 color schemes?

Tags: macos, colors, iterm2

The solarized project has a nice iTerm2 color scheme. Anyone know how to make those?

Sure, it's just an XML file with values in it but it's a pain to edit that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files are preference lists which can be edited with Xcode (or other preference list editors).

Apart from that, you can simply pick the values in the *Preferences » Colors* section, then export the theme. Click *Load Presets…*, then *Export*.

This has the advantage of being able to see the colors change in real-time.

[image]

---

If you're up for a little programming, somebody created a Groovy script that works in conjunction with Adobe Kuler to generate color schemes: [Kuler iTerm2 Themes with Groovy Scripting](http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2012/12/08/kuler-iterm2-themes-with-groovy-scripting/)

[image]

Comment: Yes, that helps a bit. The plist editor in xcode still only shows me the raw values that are present in the XML file, though. http://i.imgur.com/pzO6wR9.png

Comment: Yeah, you could probably only use a color picker to insert the proper values in Xcode, but to be honest I don't think there's a better way to edit the colors other than through iTerm itself. I updated my answer with another link to an interesting programmatic solution of the problem.